# Microphone/speakers setup via PoE

Tags: audio, ethernet, microphone

I have a few PoE (Power over Ethernet) sockets outside of my house that I use to connect PoE cameras to. One thing that I'd like to add is a microphone - or, better, a some sort of bidirectional sound setup near front door. Is there any devices on the customer market available that I can use with my setup without adding more cables? Ideally I'd like to use existing PoE lines to connect these audio devices.

A bit more context of my CCTV setup: I have a local home network with one linux server running motion camera software - it captures videos from all my cameras via RTSP protocol.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic here (and we know what poe is)

Comment: Also - if a microphone output can never be heard did it record a sound? (Ie you did not say how you envisage this sound capture being integrated/used)

Comment: I'm not looking for any particular model - I'm not sure if something that I'm looking for exists at all to begin with. I may guess that if such device exists it supports streaming sound over rtsp or similar protocol.

Also: it perhaps is possible to build a custom device supporting that - at least in theory I don't see why it shouldn't be possible from the technical standpoint. My searches to find a consumer device were in vain though - I didn't find a single device supporting what I'm looking for.

Comment: You still havnt explained it. You talk about bidirectional sound - hooked up to what?  Why not just a camera with audio where you blank the video feed?

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear enough. As for physical connectivity I meant PoE, as far as network protocol - I'm not sure. I can think of something from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_audio_network_protocols but I'm not an expert in either of those. The ideal end result as I see it would be a single device that I can plug to a PoE socket and use some VoIP protocol on the software level - whichever is simpler to setup. I'm not sure to be honest how this is usually wired on a physical level in CCTV setup allowing bidirectional audio communications - I'd be happy to learn more.

Comment: apologies for saying this, but I think you are way out of your depth - the protocols link you provided is totally inapplicable. I expect you are wanting a device that speaks SIP or maybe IAX - but you need some server infrastructure to tie this into - this is not trivial.  For a hardware **starting point** try googling SIP Intercom POE

Comment: thank you for the hint, will look into that.